# SQL query with join shows only one result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have sql query which should shows all records from table swt_modules, but it shows only first row.

```
$query1 = mysql_query ("SELECT swt_modules.id, swt_modules.name, swt_exam_regs.name AS exam_regs
                        FROM `swt_modules`
                        JOIN `swt_exam_regs`
                        USING ( `id` )
                        WHERE swt_exam_regs.id = swt_modules.exam_regulation
                        ORDER BY swt_modules.name DESC , swt_modules.id DESC
                        LIMIT " . $limit . "");
while ($fetch1 = mysql_fetch_array ($query1))
{
...
}
```

I have in this table (swt_modules) 3 rows and in each of them value of field "exam_regulation" is 1. In table swt_exam_regs I have only 1 row with 2 columns - id and name. Swt_modules.id stores id number. Which join I should use to be able to see all records?

[image: result after join]
[image: records in swt_modules table]

Comment: what is the value of `$limit` in the query ?

Comment: try using left join, instead of only join.

Comment: Do not use USING. It's confUSING.

Comment: limit is 0,10, next by button can be extended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also suggest using mysqli or pdo instead of the now deprecated mysql.

```
$query1 = mysql_query ("
    SELECT 
        swt_modules.id, 
        swt_modules.name, 
        swt_exam_regs.name AS exam_regs
    FROM swt_modules
    LEFT JOIN swt_exam_regs on swt_exam_regs.id = swt_modules.exam_regulation
    ORDER BY 
        swt_modules.name DESC, 
        swt_modules.id DESC
    LIMIT $limit");
```

Comment: it works, I can't use pdo coz I'm using old project in which I can't change it

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`. Change your query as below. Notice that, I have removed `LIMIT` since you are trying to fetch all rows.

```
SELECT swt_modules.id, swt_modules.name, swt_exam_regs.name AS exam_regs
                    FROM `swt_modules`
                    LEFT JOIN `swt_exam_regs`
                    ON swt_exam_regs.id = swt_modules.exam_regulation
                    ORDER BY swt_modules.name DESC , swt_modules.id DESC
```

Comment: It didn't change the result.

Comment: @Strawberry, that's the posted query. Sole point of my answer is to use `left join` and not `inner join`

Comment: @Beacze, if it still didn't change the result then you need to see whether you are joining on right columns between tables. I went by your posted code and so have no extra info.

Comment: @Rahul I find that response disingenuous, but your query's correct now (as far as we can ascertain from the limited information provided), so here's your point back...

Comment: @Strawberry, not sure what made you feel that about my comment. Anyways, to be honest I am not that well versed with latest MySQL syntax (that using(id)  was something new i encountered),  work in MSSQL.